# Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml for different environments

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

docker-compose for prod:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /www/node_modules
```

Dockerfile for prod:

```
FROM alpine:3.4

LABEL authors="John Doe"

RUN apk add --update nodejs bash git

COPY package.json /www/package.json
RUN cd /www; apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python && npm install && npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source && apk del builds-deps

COPY . /www

WORKDIR /www

ENV PORT 8080

EXPOSE  8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose for dev:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/www
      - /www/node_modules
```

Dockerfile for dev

```
FROM alpine:3.4

LABEL authors="John Doe"

RUN apk add --update nodejs bash git

COPY package.json /www/package.json
RUN cd /www; apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python && npm install && npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source && apk del builds-deps

WORKDIR /www

ENV PORT 8080

EXPOSE  8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I'm running it with `docker-compose up`.

Right now i have to manually make changes to files in order to change environment, which is, of course, wrong way to do this.

I assume there should be a way to avoid these manual changes. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify environment in the `services` part of the `docker-compose.yml` file.
Example:

`services:
        environment: 
           NODE_ENV: "development"

           APP_PORT: 5000
           DB_URI: "<DB URI>"`

And in your code, you can take these values by specifying `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile should contain the commands for creating the image. That image when used with docker-compose `api-server` service of yours will run the server as required.

For eg., in your case:

Your Dockerfile should look something like this.

```
FROM alpine:3.4

LABEL authors="John Doe"

RUN apk add --update nodejs bash git

RUN mkdir /www

WORKDIR /www

ADD package.json /www/package.json

RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python && npm install && npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source && apk del builds-deps
```

This will create your image.

regarding your docker-compose.yml file, use two separate docker-compose files for both production and development. Use env files to separate out development and production variables. you can check in the development docker-compose.yml and development env file in your repository, production docker-compose and environment files will be specific to your production server.

Your sample `docker-compose.yml` file should look something like this

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db
    env_file:
      development.env
    volumes:
      - ./:/www
      - /www/node_modules # I really don't understand this statement
    command: >
      /bin/ash -c "npm run dev"
```

This will be running your development server.

Similarly a same docker-compose.yml file with different ports exposed for production `-443:443` in your case and env_file to `production.env` and command set to `/bin/ash -c "npm start"` will help run your production server.

```
    version: '2'
    services:
      db:
        image: mongo:3
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
      api-server:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "443:443"
        links:
          - db
        env_file:
          production.env
        volumes:
          - ./:/www
          - /www/node_modules # I really don't understand this statement
        command: >
          /bin/ash -c "npm start"
```

In case you are running the development server and production server (never advisable) in the same machine you can create two files named `docker-compose-development.yml` and `docker-compose-production.yml` for development and production systems respectively and then you can run the server by using the command:

`sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-development.yml up`

`sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yml up`

for development and production system respectively.

Answer (score 0):

you can use environment variables as
for example 
set env as `export env="prod"` in you local machine terminal
and in docker-compose-file
`image: container_image_${env} or image: container_image:${env}`
will create images as `container_image_prod or container_image:prod`

you can also set the service name for db as `db_${env}` so that you get the service name according to the environment as `db_prod` in this case similarly you can do for other services if required